# My folders became hidden system files and access denied

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, file-recovery

I have an external HDD which suddenly seems infected and one of my folders which contain my photos changed to something like this:

[image]

One of Super User guys suggests that I install an Ubuntu and try to scan and change permissions, but I am not an Ubuntu expert, and believe me if my problem solve I will switch to it ('cause all I do is writing and taking photos. I am tired of malware, etc.)

Now I have Ubuntu and Fedora installed (after a long read through guides); both of them show infected folder as empty (in Windows 7 I see this strange folders, as you can [see in the above picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ7IG.jpg))